# Visualizing classified objects/clusters of laserscan in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a program to classify my each laser scan to find nearby objects/cluster(and all required information about those clusters) and in subsequent scans (while I am stationary, and world is moving) I am matching the new clusters with the old ones. I need help in visualizing what clusters I am getting. I am trying using MarkerArray to achieve this.

I have all the geometrical features of starting and ending point of different clusters. Now, how I create pose and position features using these physical features? Will giving slope of two points(in Cartesian coordinates) of one cluster as its pose work ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199011/visualizing-classified-objects/clusters-of-laserscan-in-rviz/) by [Akash](https://answers.ros.org/users/19915/akash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-12-06**:
if geometry of your clusters is lines,yes you can use points or  linelist. just publish them is the frame which you have their values.

**Comment by [Akash](https://answers.ros.org/users/19915/akash/) on 2014-12-06**:
I don't have any geometry right now. I just have two extreme points of all the clusters in polar form (lidar as origin) and I can find everything else using this. Can you please tell me how to create a line geometry with given two points. How should I use the published points to get a line?

**Comment by [Akash](https://answers.ros.org/users/19915/akash/) on 2014-12-06**:
And, yes, for now I am assuming my cluster to be a straight line connecting the two extreme ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Line List](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Line_List_.28LINE_LIST.3D5.29) is to draw lines for you case. Push start and end point of each line to line list variable in order.

> It will draw a line between each pair
> of points, so 0-1, 2-3, 4-5, ...

This [puslihing rviz marker lines](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines) tutorial is helpful.

---

```
    //some code with comments

    //publisher for line list marker
    ros::Publisher marker_pub = n.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("visualization_marker", 10);
    
   //variable for line list marker    
    visualization_msgs::Marker line_list;

   // frame in which you have cluster coordinates
    line_list.header.frame_id = "/world_frame";  
  
   //marker type , scale,colour
    line_list.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::LINE_LIST;
    
   line_list.scale.x = 0.1;
    
    line_list.color.r = 1.0;
    line_list.color.a = 1.0;

    // assume you have 5 lines 
    for (int  i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
        {
          geometry_msgs::Point line_start,line_end;

         // fill start and end coordinates 
          line_start.x = sx[i];
          line_start.y = sy[i];
          line_start.z = sz[i];

          line_end.x = ex[i];
          line_end.y = ey[i];
          line_end.z = ez[i];
   
          // The line list needs two points for each line
          line_list.points.push_back(line_start);
          line_list.points.push_back(line_end);
        }

        // publish marker
        marker_pub.publish(line_list);
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1